# Iframe is not working properly on IPAD devices. Only showing first page of the PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, iframe, scroll

I am trying to display the content of a pdf with an iframe. Everything is working fine on a desktop. However, on the IPAD only the first page of the pdf is getting displayed. Not able to scroll vertically or horizontally.

Here is the code I am using. Not added any external CSS

```
<iframe :src="srcUrl" id="iframe" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

I tried so many different solutions but didn't work any of it.